# iOS Push Segue (programmatically) sometimes stuck but won't crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

When I called:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:SOME_VIEW_CONTROLLER animated:YES];
```

the app randomly stuck (it didn't crash, so no error log). Have tried debugging it with no result.

Note that:

1. I called this `pushViewController` from a `UIViewController` category.
   Is there any problem with that?
2. I am not using storyboard
3. The problem persist randomly (it doesn't happen all the time)
4. When it stuck, `viewDidAppear` won't be called (`viewWillAppear, viewWillLayoutSubviews, viewDidLayoutSubviews` still
   called)
5. the problem never occured when I use animated:NO

Some code snippets:

```
- (void)routeToBookingDetailsForCustomer:(BookingModel *)booking {
    VTBookingDetailsForCustomerViewController *vc = [VTBookingDetailsForCustomerViewController new];
    vc.booking = booking;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Just found another thread with similar case:
[pushViewController stuck or viewdidappear fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094230/pushviewcontroller-stuck-or-viewdidappear-fail)

Comment: Some code would be useful...

Comment: [self.navigationController pushViewController:"view?" animated:YES];
you have written it in your code right?

Comment: R u using storyboards?

Comment: @Vidhyanand900 nope, im not using storyboard

Comment: Where is VTBookingDetailsForCustomerViewController's view made? Do you have a xib file, or are you making its view in code?

Comment: @rdelmar I am making it in code

Comment: You should post that code. There's nothing in the code you posted that's helpful in answering your question.

Comment: Could be the same issue as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503224/ios-app-freezes-on-pushviewcontroller

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to pass `Nib name` as well like this

```
- (void)routeToBookingDetailsForCustomer:(BookingModel *)booking{
    VTBookingDetailsForCustomerViewController *vc = [[VTBookingDetailsForCustomerViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"VTBookingDetailsForCustomerViewController" bundle:nil];
    vc.booking = booking;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Nib name means your `XIB name` whatever `XIB name` for your VTBookingDetailsForCustomerViewController, you have to pass this in `initWithNibName:@"yourXIBname"`

Comment: I don't get it, why should I initialized it with storyboard/nib?

Comment: Without XIB where controller pushed ?

Comment: without XIB what will display in your screen..? this need to some view(XIB) do display your design....

Comment: I changed my code to what you suggested, but it doesnt solve the problem. Moreover, as i mentioned, the problem is 'randomly occured'. If the problem is truly because there's no xib loaded, why would the view appear when the problem doesnt occur

Comment: Must be some issue in your VTBookingDetailsForCustomerViewController . Show code of viewdidload, viewdidappear.Dont comment on both threads. I'll follow this thread. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this approach?

```
someViewController *someVC = [someViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"someViewController " bundle:NULL];
someVC.someVariable  = someValue;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:someVC animated:YES];
```

Edit : Just saw 'Dipen Chudasama' already answered!

Comment: I don't get it, why should I initialized it with storyboard/nib?

Comment: Because, we have to tell the `pushViewController` that into which viewController it is going to. XIB(new name) and NIB(old name) names are same. So, we initialize class `someViewController ` and nib/xib 'someViewController' together. Because, we have to tell the `pushViewController` that into which viewController it is going to. XIB(new name) and NIB(old name) names are same. So, we initialize class `someViewController ` and nib/xib 'someViewController' together. [Refer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633940/when-and-why-to-use-initwithnibnamebundle-in-development)

Comment: I changed my code to what you suggested, but it doesnt solve the problem. Moreover, as i mentioned, the problem is 'randomly occured'. If the problem is truly because there's no xib loaded, why would the view appear when the problem doesnt occur

Comment: Must be some issue in your VTBookingDetailsForCustomerViewController . Show code of viewdidload, viewdidappear.

Comment: I don't think so, because I've removed all codes in viewdidload/viewdidappear.

update: the problem is solved when I use animated:NO
there's something wrong with the animation is it?

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310611/ios7-navigationcontroller-pushviewcontroller-animated-bug)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using custom transition animations by implementing `UINavigationProtocolDelegate` combined with `UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning`?

I struggled with this issue in my own application and it turned out that I was incorrectly starting an interactive transition which I never finished. In this case all debugging showed me that the controller was pushed but UI was not updated until my app changed states.

Answer (score 0):

Please try pushViewController code in main queue.

```
dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

VTBookingDetailsForCustomerViewController *vc = [VTBookingDetailsForCustomerViewController new];
vc.booking = booking;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

});
```